# Mongodb update a specific nested document in an array field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

how can I update `discharged` field where id is like `111` ?

```js
{
   address:'123',
   txs:[
      {id:'111',discharged:false},
      {id:'222',discharged:false}
       ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

```
db.collection.update({
  address: "123",
  "txs.id": "111"
},
{
  $set: {
    "txs.$.discharged": true
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground for Solution 1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fieLKDhem2A)

Or

**Solution 2: With arrayFilters and filtered positional operator**

```
db.collection.update({
  address: "123",
  
},
{
  $set: {
    "txs.$[tx].discharged": true
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "tx.id": "111"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground for Solution 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-joqOEocA9D)